# Spring - Use application.properties defined in parent from a library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot library which defines an HTTP interceptor for logging requests. I have inside this library a class to load properties.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "logging")
public class LoggingProperties {

    private boolean extendedLoggingEnabled;

    public boolean isExtendedLoggingEnabled() {
        return extendedLoggingEnabled;
    }

    public void setExtendedLoggingEnabled(boolean extendedLoggingEnabled) {
        this.extendedLoggingEnabled = extendedLoggingEnabled;
    }
}
```

The library is included in another Spring project, using the following class

```
@Configuration
public class LibraryConfig {

    @Bean()
    public LoggingRequestInterceptor loggingRequestInterceptor() {
        LoggingProperties properties = new LoggingProperties();
        return new LoggingRequestInterceptor(properties);
    }

}
```

In this project (the main project which included the library), I have a application.properties files with the following value among other:

```
   # logging settings
   logging.extended-logging-enabled=true
```

I want this property to be read from the library in order to apply the configuration when logging. But the property is ignored and the extendedLoggingEnabled property is always false.

Does anyone know how to make the library to use the main application.properties file?

Comment: Have you tried using a camelCase instead of kebab-case? Or using the @Value("${extended-logging-enabled}") annotation? Btw, Baeldung has great resources regarding Spring https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring. They also explain how to access the non-default properties file